# How to develop API with Hapi.js in coffeescript

Tags: hapi.js

I'm new to hapi.js and I would try test it out. Is it possible to develop with Hapi.js and coffeescript? Could you supply some example on how to setup hapi.js with coffeescript.

Comment: To the person giving a down vote to my question, please explain why. Don't just vote down a question. I think it's a legit question. THanks

Answer (score 1):

I thought the same approach would be useful. From [CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org):

> The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript". The code compiles one-to-one into the equivalent JS, and there is no interpretation at runtime. You can use any existing JavaScript library seamlessly from CoffeeScript (and vice-versa). The compiled output is readable and pretty-printed, will work in every JavaScript runtime, and tends to run as fast or faster than the equivalent handwritten JavaScript.

If you know CoffeeScript, then you should be able to translate all examples into CoffeeScript by yourself. Else, you should learn CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste any example code into http://js2.coffee and it will show you how it may look like in coffeescript.

And yes you could easily use coffeescript also with hapi like:

```
Hapi = require 'hapi'
server = new Hapi.Server()
server.connection
  port: 3000
server.start ->
  console.log 'Server running at:', server.info.uri
```